# Koin singleton inject constructor with private parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, singleton, koin

Hello I am just learning Koin, how would this Dagger2 class be provided in Koin 2.0?

```
@Singleton
open class AppExecutors(private val diskIO: Executor, private val networkIO: Executor, private val mainThread: Executor) {

    @Inject
    constructor() : this(
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1),
            MainThreadExecutor())

    fun diskIO(): Executor {
        return diskIO
    }

    fun networkIO(): Executor {
        return networkIO
    }

    fun mainThread(): Executor {
        return mainThread
    }

    private class MainThreadExecutor : Executor {
        private val mainThreadHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        override fun execute(command: Runnable) {
            mainThreadHandler.post(command)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
single<AppExecutors> { AppExecutors(
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1),
    AppExecutors.MainThreadExecutor())
}
```

But `AppExecutors.MainThreadExecutor()` is private. Is the only solution to make it public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a bit strange idea to inject something that is a private implementation detail from outside using DI.

Also the solution in Dagger2 is a trick which actually works around the dependency injection.

So you need to do the decision: do I want it to be a private implemietation detail? If yes I would suggest to use a default parameter value and use injection only when you need to override this implementation e.g. for testing.

```
open class AppExecutors(
    private val diskIO: Executor, 
    private val networkIO: Executor, 
    private val mainThread: Executor = AppExecutors.MainThreadExecutor()) {
```

And:

```
single<AppExecutors> { AppExecutors(
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1)))
}
```

(Keep in mind that using default paramter values in Kotlin is in the end the same as using multiple constructors in the original example.)

Otherwise you should make it public and extract it from the class.

Comment: Brilliant ok I knew something felt weird that makes sense that it's a pretty funky thing to do anyway. It is from an official sample (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/migrations/AppExecutors.java) which is why I didn't really question it :D

Comment: @DanielWilson to be fair: it's, in the end, the same as using the default parameter values in Kotlin. It's a perfectly valid solution to the problem. I just wanted to emphasize that even the original solution you had in dagger wasn't actually doing dependency injection in a pure way.